# Pivoting data.frame with multiple "columns" per column

Tags: r, pivot, tidyverse

Consider the following:

```
tribble(
  ~"1", ~"2", ~"3", ~"4",
  "bob", "sally", "fred","jim",
  "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014"
)
```

In the above, column "1" stores values that we really want to be to separate columns, such:

```
tribble(
  ~col, ~name, ~year,
  "1", "bob", "2011",
  "2", "sally", "2012",
  "3", "fred", "2013",
  "4", "jim", "2014"
)
```

At first, I tried `pivot_longer(everything())` but that produces duplicate rows.

```
  name  value
  <chr> <chr>
1 1     bob  
2 2     sally
3 3     fred 
4 4     jim  
5 1     2011 
6 2     2012 
7 3     2013 
8 4     2014
```

I considered then trying `pivot_wider`, but I can't partially select either the years or names in the value column above.

Any ideas? This is a toy example of course - the basic idea is to take multiple rows and covert them to columns without needing to repeat the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is all mixed up. If we have more such values we need to specify a way in which we can identify each group.

Here I have considered values with only characters in them as `name`, values with only numbers in them as `year`, you can add more such conditions if needed.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = 'col') %>%
  mutate(col_name = case_when(grepl('^[A-Za-z]+$', value) ~ 'name', 
                              grepl('^[0-9]+$', value) ~'year')) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col_name, values_from = value) %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)

# A tibble: 4 x 3
#    col name   year
#  <int> <chr> <int>
#1     1 bob    2011
#2     2 sally  2012
#3     3 fred   2013
#4     4 jim    2014
```

Comment: This solution scales to more cases and stays in tidyverse! Cool way to solve this problem - also being able to leverage case_when gives a lot of flexability.

Answer (score 5):

An easy solution is

```
tibble::rownames_to_column(as.data.frame(t(A)))
```

with output

```
  rowname    V1   V2
1       1   bob 2011
2       2 sally 2012
3       3  fred 2013
4       4   jim 2014
```

where

```
> A = tribble(
+     ~"1", ~"2", ~"3", ~"4",
+     "bob", "sally", "fred","jim",
+     "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014"
+ )
```

Edit:

You can also use the pipe like this

```
A %>% t() %>% as.data.frame() %>% tibble::rownames_to_column()
```

Comment: Ya, I was thinking about this one. We have to add a new line to rename the columns, but I think this is a good solution.

Comment: Yeah, it is brief and does the job. Also, in case the answer solved your question, you may indicate that by checking the mark.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this directly with `data.table::transpose`

```
data.table::transpose(df1, keep.names = 'rn')
#  rn    V1   V2
#1  1   bob 2011
#2  2 sally 2012
#3  3  fred 2013
#4  4   jim 2014
```